# Converting 4 bytes (from String format) into one u32. C or C#

Tags: c#, c

I am attempting to convert some text from a text field to a(n) u32 value. An example would be that I enter in string format (to represent a 32-bit integer), "0x30323436", and the output in string format would be "0246". I am trying to do this in C#, but I can use C as well. Thank you.

Comment: I don't get it. How do you get "0246" from "30323436" ? If the original notation is hexadecimal, then the decimal value is 808596534, not 246.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand... the original notation is actually the ASCII codes of the digits, in hexadecimal. You should really mention this in your question, we're not supposed to guess this kind of thing

Comment: If you really just need to go from string to string, and your input is correct, you can just extract every other character.

Comment: Oh, hadn't realized. I am used to recognizing hex as ascii. Didn't realize others thought I meant decimal. L.B, That would be great but hex includes the letters A - F. So 30323436 should be said as 0x30323436.

Comment: I can use that method in C. Just have to add some letter specific if statements for the letters and a less than 0x40 for the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
string ParseWeirdFormat(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 2)
    {
        string hex = input.Substring(i, 2);
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
        char c = (char)value;
        sb.Append(c);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Actually, there is a problem if the text is 00, then it ends the string. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I fixed it. Should be writing in byte format, not text format. It thinks that 00 is the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

This is why C is cooler than C#:

```
char in[] = "0x30323436";
char out[5] = {0};
sscanf( in, "0x%02x%02x%02x%02x", &out[0], &out[1], &out[2], &out[3] );
```

Answer (score 0):

In C (C99 or above):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static bool cvt(const char* in, char* out)
{
    if (strlen(in) != 8)
        return false;

    char* end;
    long n = strtol(in, &end, 16);
    if (end == in || *end)
        return false;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        unsigned char c = n >> ((3-i)*8);
        if(!isdigit(c))
            return false;
        out[i] = c;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char out[4];

    if ( argc <= 1 || !cvt(argv[1], out) )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s hex-ASCII-encoding-of-four-digit-string\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%.4s\n", out);

    return 0;
}
```